# (Access names from closed excel worksheet through VB.NET.) What is wrong with this?

Tags: vb.net, excel

a) I have assigned a name "abc" to range A3 to G3 using name manager functionality in excel 2007

b) I want to access this name from VB.NET to assign values in a loop

How to do this? I am new to VB.NET

Excel workbook will not be open

I tried it using usual VBA like code.

```
For i = 1 To k

costs("abc").RefersToRange.Cells(3, i).value = "Cost" & i
```

Errors:

1) 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

2) Loop control variable cannot be a property or a late-bound indexed array.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the range as follows. This finds all the values from a range named `abc` that is defined as `A3:G3` in the first worksheet of an excel file:

```
    'initialise the objects and open the file
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\foo\book1.xlsx")
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        xlSheet.Range("abc").Cells(1, i).value = "Cost" & i.ToString
    Next

    'save file
    xlWorkBook.Save()
    'close objects and clean up
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    xlSheet = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using Excel 2007 or above, you can create and edit Excel workbooks without opening Excel itself using the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). Instead of using Interop to access Excel, the SDK works against the "raw" Excel file. I haven't specifically worked with named ranges, but there is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298533) which uses them and should help you get started.